# Defeating a Poker Bot

Tags: security, artificial-intelligence, poker

There is a new Open Source poker bot called [PokerPirate](http://www.robotpoker.org/).  I am interested in any creative ways in which a web application could detect/thwart/defeat a poker bot.  (This is a purely academic discussion,  in the same spirit that PokerPirate was written.)

Comment: I presume you mean "any *more* ways", given that the top/first answer is your own :-)

Comment: Excellent question, should get some very interesting answers here.

Comment: Talk to each player.

Comment: @Lasse: hmm, that's not enough if the player is a bot that passes the Turing test

Comment: Regardless or not if it could pass the turing test, it doesn't stop the bot creator sitting at the tables and spending all his time chatting.

Comment: The best approach is to do what Vegas does: rig the rules of the game so the only winning strategy is to be the house, and then be the house. At that point all a bot does is loose money faster, and you can quit caring.

Comment: @BCS, poker can be profitable, but it's difficult.  It is one of the few games you can play in a casino where you have any realistic chance of winning.  The other is blackjack, but again, it is difficult.

Comment: @Tom, so there are two games that you can win at and I happened to pick the one I didn't know  about to comment on :) Ironic.

Comment: Telling people to avoid it as it's an unprofitable, could easily lead to misery, addiction and depression, wasteful of money and time, and dangerous potentially self harming and life wasting route to take is never a bad thing, and I don't mind people offering that advice, but in an academic environment I prefer to let people know the truth :)  I've seen ugly people, violent people, wasted people and people on the road to being wasters, thugs, losers through this game.  Casinos are some of the most disgusting and depressing environments you could exist in.  Best to avoid it if you ask me.

Comment: @Rook - You don't [frolic boisterously](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=gambol)? I'm disappointed. You definitely *seemed* like the romping in meadows type...

Comment: @ire_and_curses  lol you must know me in real life.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

**Defeating a bot from the serverside perspective**

1. Many online poker sites use popup
   [Captcha](http://www.cardschat.com/f10/poker-stars-close-encounters-captcha-kind-115779/) inputs that are triggered by
   suspicious activity.
2. Some poker sites monitor playing
   times and patterns (i.e., worst case
   scenario is a player who plays 24x7
   and 16 tables continuously, there is
   a tiny tiny chance this is a real
   human. (However some players [do have the ability to play very large hand volumes](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/54/poker-beats-brags-variance/boku87-challenge-2-update-finished-533223/index270.html) which to the inexperienced eye would appear to be a bot)
3. Throw it glitches.  If you suspect a
   player is a bot, change all their
   playing card positions off a few
   pixels on the screen, make them
   different colours/designs/patterns
   for 1/100 hands and see if it throws
   them.  If it can't screen grab it
   will time-out on all its decisions
   and that's pretty conclusive bot
   evidence.
4. Timing tells, if a computer player
   responds to options in milliseconds
   at a time without pause for thought
   on large decisions this could be
   suspicious
5. Self monitoring.  The poker website
   [pokertableratings.com](http://www.pokertableratings.com) data
   mines a lot of large sites.  It has
   been met with a mixed reception,
   some love the transparency, [others
   hate it](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/view-you-ptr-778621/).  The benefit is, however,
   that [there have been instances
   where suspicious player
   statistics](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/ub-scandal-sticky-251207/) (VPIP percentages,
   PFR percentages are a few of a large
   number of quantifiable statistics
   that can be recorded) have lead to
   conclusions of cheating
6. Artificially intelligent
   [classification networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) could
   monitor quantifiable statistics to
   classify rogue cheating or robotic
   players.
7. Back when online poker was a fairly
   new entity, there was rumour [and talk](http://igamingforums.com/iGaming/TopReasonsLeavePartyPoker/vgldh/post.htm) with limited evidence that
   some poker client software
   screen-shots of suspicious players
   desktops to see if they were running
   programs that assist them.  However (even if this were true) running two computers to perform the two tasks independently would get around this.
8. Sharing information between repeat
   offenders between multiple sites
   would be beneficial to the industry,
   [if only they were honourable](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/ub-scandal-sticky-251207/) and run by [competent responsible people](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/another-hole-ub-ap-security-778002/)
9. Some bots would probably be quite
   simple by design, if you could discover their
   playing style and see how they act
   in identical situations (note this
   is only possible with
   unsophisticated bots playing very
   basic strategy) you could discover
   them reasonably quickly.
10. Inconsistent use of program
     features would lean towards a
     player being genuine.  Take for
     example many poker sites in game
     have a 'Fold when it's my turn'
     button.  If you get dealt a bad
     hand and are waiting for another
     player to decide what to do, a lot
     of players will check this button. 
     A bot may use these buttons.  The
     difference is, a bot would be on the extremities of frequency of use, they would probably either use them all the time, or not at all.
     Wheras a player might usually press
     'autofold', but sometimes they will
     click fold anyway even in the most
     favorable conditions.  For example,
     a genuine player usually presses
     auto fold but this time they don't.
     It's folded round to them with no
     other player acting, now they have
     been presented with the most
     favourable condition possible.  Now
     if they press fold, they would have
     been heavily inclined to press autofold from the start.  This is
     inconsistant/unoptimised/random
     behaviour, consistant with being a
     human.  Timing tells on when these features are clicked are other indicators.  It is important to recognise that these are all indicators and not conclusive proof.  All of these behavioural indicators can be simulated easily.

**Defeating a bot from a players perspective**

10. Try to log and collect as much data as possible using software like [PokerTracker](http://www.pokertracker.com)
11. Attempt to identify patterns in
     its playing style
12. Attempt to find relationships
     between bet size in proportion to
     pot/# players and hand strength
13. Try to calculate its [hand ranges](http://www.pokerstove.com/).  A low stakes bot probably wont be bluffing frequently enough to be of any significant strategic concern, so constructing highly accurate hand ranges for it shouldn't be too tricky.
14. Attempt to find [leaks](http://www.poker-strategy.org/default.aspx?tabid=165) in its
     game via data analysis and trial
     and error Once leaks/patterns have
     been found, attempt to repetitively
     exploit them and avoid any other
     situations.

Where a human is capable of [adaptation](http://www.docbluminc.com/adapting-to-different-poker-playing-styles/), bots probably are less so, and where humans are weighted by the chains of [tilt](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/54/poker-beats-brags-variance/things-people-do-casinos-tilt-you-755425/), [results orientated thinking](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/39/small-stakes-pl-nl/worst-ev-graph-time-quit-766211/) and [frustrations](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/54/poker-beats-brags-variance/straw-broke-camels-back-820163/), bots are not.  You can use this to your advantage.

So in essence there is nothing you can do to stop it if the robot is clever enough to simulate real timing delays during decisions, as well as create reasonable and realistic playing patterns.  Throw in some random conditions and simple back-chat (the poker players lexicon is [**usually fairly limited**](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/54/poker-beats-brags-variance/dont-you-hate-when-they-say-ty-38508/)) and you have yourself a AI player that's going to be pretty hard to detect.

**What bots might do to avoid detection**

The key to avoid detection would be to think about the problem from as many angles as possible.  You are attempting to simulate intelligent human behaviour in a very small and restricting world.  Most of the behavioural simulations you can run are fairly obvious, but the more inconsistant and unpredictable your bot is, the less likely it is to be discovered.

1. Create realistic playing schedules
   (i.e., 3–5 times a week, 4 hours per
   session with the odd week here and
   there off during the year).
2. Run programs to make decisions on
   separate computer, controlling a
   zombie computer in case any sites
   screen capture.
3. Randomise action timings (don't act
   immediately, wait 0.5–2 seconds per
   action)
4. Time down on big decisions.  If a
   decision is borderline, calculate
   the decision then wait a while to
   simulate thought.
5. Random use of client software features. 
   Simulate toilet breaks by clicking
   the "deal me out button" on all the
   tables and have a 5 minute break
   every now and then.
6. Simulated chat, poker chat is often
   very simple one liners, never
   usually discussion or debate.  Say
   things like "unlucky" or "stfu" at
   appropriate detectable moments.  Or
   even have the coder monitoring his
   bot and engaging in chat during
   execution.
7. Ensure mouse movements are
   realistic.  If tables are
   [tiled](http://www.pokerstars.com/poker/room/features/re-sizing/) don't make a decision on
   top left table then instantly make
   on on bottom right table.  Most sites software now offer keyboard shortcuts, these may be preferable to use as supposed to mousemovement.
8. Do things that quite simply AI
   classifiers wont be expecting.  For
   example, once a year phone them up
   with a simple non-complex query ("Help I can't
   log in today!" or "The Internet is down!")  Unlikely to make much difference, but if the person working for the poker company is smart enough they might have recognised it as a realiable indicator.
9. Sporadic losing sessions.  Tilt can
   be simulated and the bot can play
   badly and lose some money every now
   and then.  *Everybody* tilts at some
   point.

The concern is also that poker websites don't particularly care if bots are running on their networks, each player is worth a large amount in rake and theoretically from a purely cynical business point of view the only downside would be bad press if it was discovered.

Even when blatant exploits have been discovered, (search on google for [Cereus network](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&q=cereus+network+scandal&aq=f&aqi=g4g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=b574888f9dc97a30) scandals or [Absolute Poker Scandal](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=tom+scott+absolute+poker+scandal&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=b574888f9dc97a30), it's quite shocking) the business appears to survive and remain healthy, only losing well educated and winning players (of which there are not many).  This increases the proportion of less skilled players to the network, which in turn attracts the good players back.  It's a good ol' fashioned catch 22.  An excellent argument for proper market regulation.

It is important to note, that for every game a nash [equilibrium exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium).  Online poker has a timeline to it the way it runs now, it's going to have to move into something more social (webcam/voip) for anyone to trust it in the future (if people trust it) as bots will take over eventually as mathematically superior, and psychologically immune.  The poker AI community is [very active](http://pokerai.org/pj2/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=1), fuelled by academia and/or capital benefit.

Simpler versions of poker such as limit poker have been [very nearly solved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris_%28poker_bot%29) in small search spaces.  It's only a matter of time before more complex versions of the game (No Limit variations/[Pot Limit Omaha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha_hold_%27em) etc) become beatable for artificial players.

**Conclusion**

Sophisticated bots just can't be detected until the industry shifts to a more social online gaming setting.  This won't solve the problem, but will certainly make it harder for bots to win at the lower levels.  We've already seen a slight shift with the release of [PKR](http://www.pkr.com), [3D and a more interactive](http://www.completepokerreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/pkr-s2.jpg), less hands per hour version of the other sites where multitabling is quite tricky to accomplish for a player.

The problem also suffers from the nature of the industry, yet another reason to stick to the larger more reputable websites where reputation has become more and more integrated into their business model.  Lack of transparency and [feigned transarancy](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/annie-duke-inconsistency-thread-cereus-related-811953/) don't help the cause.

The real challenge currently for bot developers is to write a winning algorithm, this is not as trivial as it seems.  Everyone who plays poker considers themselves good, winning or a break even player, which is simply not true.  That is why people continue to play, even when they lose money as they are under the illusion they are simply unlucky, or their style of play is misunderstood.  This arrogance and weakness in human psychology has cost losing players a lot of money and is the fundamental reason that poker can still be profitable.

Poker is a vastly complicated game that takes years to get good at (The old adage remains true, "Ten minutes to learn, a lifetime to master").  The luck element is extremely limited in the long term.

Like any other profession, to get good, you need to study for hundreds upon hundreds of hours, and play for many thousands.  You will understand things that less experienced players wont understand, spot things the less experienced wont spot.  The learning goes on for a very very long time, perhaps longer than we can ever live.  It's a complicated game.

How often have you seen a high stakes cash game on the television and heard someone shout at it "That's an easy call!" thus prooving that amateurs really don't understand or recognise sophistication in play, and truly beleive the game at that level is still ultimately simple. It isn't.  Those high stakes players (a lot of the time) are there on the television because they are really *really* **really** good.  There is also probably a complicated meta game being played as well, which our amauer can't recognise the existance of.  The amatuer wouldn't stand over a chess master and shout at them to move their knight, yet because of the dynamic of poker being imperfect information their psychology makes them truly beleive what they are saying.  Like in chess, decisions can be intricate, sensitive and extremely important to the overall game.  As the game increases in complexity, trivial decisions are not so trivial anymore, because your opponent expects them.

Once you move your bot or your game up the levels, you inevitably will come across a larger populous of more skilled players.  Then, the complexity of your strategy is going to have to go up to the next level, taking into account [table images](http://www.duluthpoker.com/strategy/poker/table-image/), [range balancing](http://www.pokerlistings.com/strategy/general-poker/balancing-your-range), sophisticated and intelligent bluffing (IE not just bluffing at weakness, bluffing at ranges and bluffing on image etc), with more detailed hand range analysis.  It really is a different game as you move up.

Once a winning bot has been written, without doubt the coder will have enough skill, knowledge and common sense to apply the bot in an undetectable fashion.  This is trivial for them.

So there really is nothing you can do.  If you want to play online, understand the risks.  Never risk more money than you can afford, and attempt to keep accurate records of spending so you don't have a misguided, unrealistic and ultimately damaging over estimation of your own ability.  Have stop losses, and leave the table if you don't have an edge, or if you are unsure if you have an edge!  Of course, if everyone did that no one would win, that's the predatory and exploitative nature of the game, that's where the competition comes from and that's what makes it fun.

Comment: At least in the days of analog monitors, it would be possible to have a screen-grabber running on a computer that was entirely separate from the one playing the game.  Detecting such a thing in the game's software would be completely impossible, of course.  Even if HDCP wouldn't allow one to do such a thing with a modern computer's video output, one could always use a precisely-aimed camera.  If cards are easily readable by a human, a machine will have no trouble.

Comment: Nowadays you could even run the game on a VM and the bot outside of it, capturing images and sending keyboard/mouse events.

Comment: Take a look at OpenHoldem. The thing even has some DLL extensions to simulate mouse jitter and human-like mouse acceleration for clicking the buttons. If your code generates probability triples for Call or Check/Fold/Raise, it's going to be hard to locate patterns without possibly thousands of hands.

Answer (score 9):

There are three separate areas to consider.  The bot has to figure out the state of the table, make a decision, and send the decision back to the host.

Figuring out the state of the table is much easier if it is sent across the wire in some recognizable form or displayed to the user as standard text.  First, make image recognition the only option, then make it as hard as possible.  Display the cards in 3D and slowly change the orientation and position of the cards.  Animate little flickers or fireworks in front of the cards so any given screen shot may be illegible but it takes a while even to determine that.

There is nothing to be done with making the decision. Trying to decide if a decision was made by a human or not is like a turing test with almost no information.

Sending the decision back can be made difficult by using 3D again.  Make it hard to send packets directly or otherwise submit a decision by any means other than clicking a button with the mouse.  Move the buttons slightly with every action or have them float slowly around the play area while awaiting a decision.  Disable any accessibility type features that allow buttons to be found or manipulated.

Comment: Security through difficulty.  Assuming you are allowed to stream a rendered video of the game, the goal is to make it a moving CAPTCHA.

Comment: @drawnonward  interesting idea,  but this is over HTTP and thats the weakest link.  You should try writing exploit code :)

Comment: @The Rook: PokerPirate, which you reference in your question, has absolutely nothing to do with HTTP. In fact, I doubt there are any gambling poker sites that use HTTP. Your question, answer, and comments reveal that you know very little about this subject. You should try knowing what you're talking about before giving advice to people about what they should do. :)

Comment: I absolutely agree with drawnonward and RarrRarrRarr. However, it does essentially require a streaming video version of the game as drawnonward said, or at least the whole screen must be one image (a dumb client, if you will). Otherwise for example if you implement the 3D and the effects in something like Java or Flash, someone can easily modify the web app to remove those fancy effects, or even build the bot on top of the web app to hook directly into its code. Or could figure out the network protocol and write an AI that directly sends/receives packets in the game's native protocol.

Comment: Of course, you've just annoyed the heck out of the human player, who gets a streaming video of his cards being waved around and obscured, rather than a nice easy-to-read display.  Not to mention you've restricted me to chasing buttons around with my mouse, and have chased away anybody with certain disabilities.  Playing poker on-line with my cards and my mouse clicks requiring close and continued attention - how the heck am I going to pay attention to what my opponents actually bet?

Comment: @David this is not a question about usability, and usability usually suffers at the cost of security.  Wouldn't it be nice if nobody ever had to type in passwords online, like at banks, because that would be much more usable.

Comment: @drawnonward:  If usability is totally not a concern, you can have security by cutting all data connections, which is arguably a creative way of stopping cheating.  I don't see how to evaluate security measures except in the context of usability.

Comment: @David Which is why people accept the necessity of passwords on banking sites.  As long as people understand that the annoyance has value, and the annoyance does not exceed the value, there is balance.  If you have a better solution then post it.

Comment: @drawnonward:  Sure, but (a) I can't go to a banking site without a password, (b) banking is more of a necessity to most people than online poker, and (c) it isn't a continuing annoyance that will persist for a long time.  This solution will likely be worse than the original problem.

Comment: The original problem is ensuring only humans play poker on a web page.  With a bank site, once you enter your password you gain the trust of the host.  In this case there is nothing you can do to gain the continued trust of the host, so the security challenge must be continuous.

Comment: Ultimately this is an impossible question, even without usability being a factor.  Quibbling about usability misses the point.

Answer (score 8):

PokerPirate, like nearly every poker bot ever written, works by screen scraping and simulating mouse clicks in a Windows poker application. Therefore, the lynch-pin to the system is its ability recognize objects in the game and make actions in the window. As smart as it may be at poker, it likely still has trouble with these basic operations.

Therefore, Obvious ways to thwart this bot would include:

1. Implement a CAPTCHA, either before the game, or when other factors suggest a player may be a bot.
2. Make the table graphics more complicated, or change theme throughout the game.
3. Detect unusually fast and/or robotic mouse movements and clicks (a human will never move a mouse in a mathematically perfect line).

Comment: The majority of this is Security though obscurity.  All of this can be broken,  including the captcha.  Although I admit that is the hardest part to break. (+1 There isn't a 100% solution and much of this described could be used with other techniques.)

Comment: How good are captcha bots now, anyway? I'll tell you this: half of the images I get from Google Apps are impossible for a *human* to read.

Comment: All computer security is through obscurity. The reason why someone can't read an encrypted email is because they can't easily find the private key. But given enough time and computing resources, that too can be "broken". Most captchas are pretty good and will weed out 99.99% of the bots.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally the only valid solution is to create a honeypot logic that lures an engaged bot by providing the temptation of a more favorable logic condition that favors the bot's most ideal behavioral responses.  Once the bot is engaged in the honeypot you must continually feed the bot conditions that it prefers presuming the bot does not have a set timeout.  Then the bot can be measured, logged, and studied.  In addition to the bot you would also have the network and session data isolated for study provided the bot is not connecting via TOR.

In this situation deterministic considerations suited to differentiating a bot from a human are less severe, however, deterministic consideration upon identification of the bot's behavior become more severe.  Unfortunately, the bot's owner can make changes to the bot to prevent such identification if that owner is aware of the honeypot condition, or the logical consideration thereof.

Comment: Quoting Sun Tzu: "Know your enemy". Avoid his strengths, and explore his weaknesses.

Comment: Its not a bad idea and I'm interested in what this software would look like.   Do you care to elaborate on a specific condition?

Comment: Tor exit points are fairly limited. Any player that connects via a tor exist points should be suspicious.

Comment: Creating a honeypot could get very expensive for a poker site

Comment: You can just make it think it is making money.

Comment: False positives are going to lose you customers if you fake honeypot them.  Could even lead to lawsuits.

Answer (score 4):

Defeating poker bots can take two forms: you can try and identify them and ban them from the system, or you can just beat them at poker. Beating them at poker is the more interesting academic question. :-)

See here for some papers about beating poker bots: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sganzfri/

Answer (score 3):

[Look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143231/protection-against-automation)

[This post](http://www.chessdiscussion.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=937) also has some good tips on how to thwart them.

Answer (score 2):

Another thought on messing with the screen to make it hard to scan:

Make the card out of a whole slew of different colors--close in human eye terms but not the same.  This would make it harder to pick out the stuff to read.  On the flip side, put fake writing on the card in colors that the human eye won't separate from the background.

Comment: Unfortunatly this would be quite easy to defeat for any competant programmer, as they would screen scrape colour ranges and not exact values bypassing this solution.

Comment: Color ranges would work if they were fixed--but what if you kept changing things?  It would mean that your scraper would have to be programmed to understand human vision.  It wouldn't be impossible but it would make things much harder.

Comment: Plausible but it's going to significantly detract from valid users experience of the software which is probably bad business.

Comment: Very easy to defeat. I've written a poker bot before, and I do card-recognition by calculating image similarity within a bounding box. Even if none of the pixels are exactly the same (either because the card colors or the screen location are slightly changed on every had), I can still use those similarity measurements to identify the "most likely" card.

Comment: And why do you think the colors must remain even similar?  Cycle them through wildly different colors and cycle the background--I'm picturing an effect like a wave that keeps sweeping across the cards and changing the colors.  Keep plenty of contrast and make sure the colors that result aren't ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Is the problem with bots the fact that they play better than decent human players, or that they can wait around 24/7 for bad players to appear and then try to milk them?

Also, would it be "legitimate" or "cheating" for someone to have a computer sitting next to him while he played poker, consulting that other computer for advice?

I'm not sure how one can claim the solution space for limit poker is "solved" when the optimal strategy for a player will be influenced by what is known about the opponents.  How can any attempt at analyzing players claim to be so perfect that it could not be improved?

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion on if poker is solvable:
http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/29/news-views-gossip/view-can-poker-solved-792664/
Some of the posters in there are very reputable.
The problem is that theoretically a bot will perform in an unbeatable manner.  Also, software you describe to 'help' you is a grey area, many sites allow data analysis software such as PokerTracker/PokerOffice, but draw the line at ICM calculators and other mathmatical decision making tools (for example, these are extremely useful in hyper turbo tournament end game strategy).

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a lot of matches, you can take a data mining approach. The playing strength of an AI should be pretty consistent, while there are probably simple patterns for humans - weaker in the first few warm-up rounds, and strength deteriorates after playing for a long time. Also, human decision times probably go up when there is more money at stake.

If you have access to mouse moves (or at least click locations which is true even for web apps), it should be fairly simple to recognize bots, except for the most sophisticated ones. Humans don't move the mouse in an exact straight line, they have speedup and slowdown periods, statistically describable click location distributions, etc.

Comment: A lot of poker sites now implement keyboard shortcuts for multitabling, so you can remove the need for a mouse at all in a bot.  I also don't think decision goes up with money at stake often, it's primarially correlated to difficulty of decision.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Ajax Control Toolkit NoBot](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_NoBot.ashx):

> NoBot employs a few different anti-bot techniques:

```
* Forcing the client's browser to perform a configurable JavaScript calculation and verifying the result as part of the postback. (Ex: the calculation may be a simple numeric one, or may also involve the DOM for added assurance that a browser is involved)

* Enforcing a configurable delay between when a form is requested and when it can be posted back. (Ex: a human is unlikely to complete a form in less than two seconds)

* Enforcing a configurable limit to the number of acceptable requests per IP address per unit of time. (Ex: a human is unlikely to submit the same form more than five times in one minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

A 100% solution is impossible, what I am purposing is a solution that will save money by using the AI against its self. Have an instance of [PokerPirate's AI](http://www.robotpoker.org/PokerPirate/ai.html#ai) running on the server side and playing as an invisible player in every game. If any player performs too many identical actions then they are probably running an instance of PokerPirate.  This is a kind of [Honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)) or trap that the attacker can fall into.  The attacker can defend against this honeypot by making their bot less successful.  Thus this is creating a came of "Cat and Mouse" in which the attacker can always steal *some* money and the defender can always save *some* money.

Comment: Shame you deleted your other almost identical answer, as it contained interesting feedback.

Comment: This assumes there is only one poker playing bot, and that a human would never do the same things a bot would.

Comment: @drawnonward A human isn't going to act like a bot *all of the time*,  there is a fuzz factor here.

Comment: The problem with doing that for a poker bot is that their actions are generally pretty fuzzy in that they don't do the same thing every time given the same circumstances. There's a large element of randomness (at least in the AI I've written).

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I don't know how well it will scale. What happens when more Poker AI programs are written? Are you going to run a copy of every single one with every single game you host? Also, I don't know anything about PokerPirate, but it seems like this method won't work if the author of the AI adds randomness to the program. Now, you will either have to make your program stricter (resulting in many more false positives), or give players some leeway (resulting in more false negatives and more cheaters getting away with it).

Comment: @The Rook: So how is that effective at all?

Comment: @TheRook 'Gamboling "AI's" should be purely mathematical and there is always the "right answer".' That's only true in games of complete information of which poker is not one.  A player that always takes the same action given the same state becomes predictable and thus easy to defeat.  The best bots will have elements of randomness.  Even the most mathematical of players will recommend varying behavior even in the same situation (usually with some % probability).

Comment: @musicfreak Judging by this post and your other security posts on SO I fundamentally and completely disagree with your security philosophy.

Comment: @Davy8  In an academic setting it is proper to provide sources to back your arguments.

Comment: @The Rook I wasn't this was an academic setting, however I did dig up one reference (and pretty much any serious poker book you pick up will agree that at a high level of play unpredictability is crucial) http://www.sciencenews.org/sn_arc98/7_18_98/bob1.htm Some quotes: `"We've been working on categorizing and understanding styles of play, [...] it gets more difficult in games against top players because they mix up their play deliberately to confuse you." Being unpredictable is a good strategy, he adds. "If our computer is going to beat the world champion, it's got to do something similar."`

Comment: This would fail for several reasons, the main being that many bots for obvious reasons are closed source, or modified versions of poker pirate.  Another reason would be that any bot worth it's salt would base it's actions on quantifiable data gathered from it's observations, these observations would differ from each instance of the bot.

Comment: @Davy, I don't play at a high level, but you are correct in saying unpredictability is crucial.  Howver, randomness is a slightly more tricky area, where the randomness and unpredictability is not actually random, but is a mathmatically balanced act.  Look up 'poker balancing' on google for more information.  It's crucial for strategy as you play in the higher limits.

Comment: @Tom Gullen  I still think that if you look at a players actions over time that patterns will emerge,  a computer will always make different choices than a human (for now).  In a sense any game with definite rules can be used as a Turing test.

Comment: Possibly, but the big problem here is quanitifying those patterns, as they are very sensitive to their environment.

Answer (score -2):

There are much easier ways.
yes. a lot of the suggestions are right, and needed.
but about 90% of the frauds are detected in too simple manner.

if someone let a bot work for him,
he will, after some time, want that a second bot is working for him. (another machine or whatsoever)
but: he will use the same password,  as it is hard to remember 2 (<--- sarcastic)

whats left:
**check the accounts with same game behavior and same password hash.**

Comment: How is it reliable ? I guess A LOT of different people are using the same password. Don't even get me started with password like their birthdate, or simply "azerty" or "password".

Comment: @WCWedin  good call,  all password hashes should use a unique salt.

Comment: @DuoSRX true, not reliable, but a good hint.
the whole list of results goes to the fraud team, and they make a background check on the accounts.
@WCWedin yes. nobrainer ;-)